# Is there a way to display only one row with total sum , Currently its displaying two rows as output

Tags: php, mysqli

I have four  columns  ( Driver ID , Start time , end time , minutes spent ) 
When User logins start time column will be filled and when user logouts  end time will be filled and total minutes will be calculated . And everytime when user logins  new row will be inserted

I'm trying to display total minutes  spent on  each particular day

For example

```
Date (13 - 2  - 2019) -  630 minutes  spent 

Date ( 12 - 2 - 2019) -  450 minutes  spent 
etc...
```

But in my case  12 -2 -2019(4AM) to 13 -2 - 2019(3.59AM) is considered as one day

from backend its coded in such a way that if user has logged from (13-2-2019)(2am) to (13-2-2019)(6AM)  .. it will store two rows on database.
like below :-

```
Driver ID  |  start time      | End time           | min spent 

3229       |  (13-2-2019)(2am)| (13-2-2019)(3.59am)|    120

3229       |  (13-2-2019)(4am) (13-2-2019)(6.00am) |   120
```

From above example the 1st row min spent should be for 12-2-2019 Date . For this i have used BETWEEN query as below .

Below query will output two results : -

```
$sql = "SELECT * , date(start_time),sum(minutes_spent) FROM 
driver_online_session where driver_id='3229' AND
start_time    BETWEEN '2019-02-12 03:59:59' AND  '2019-02-13 03:59:59'
 GROUP by date(start_time)
 ORDER BY start_time DESC";
```

[image]

Current Output :-

```
id  3229  date : 2019-02-13 01:07:20  min spent : 61

id: 3229  date : 2019-02-12 04:00:00  min spent : 1024
```

My expected output should be

```
id  3229  date : 2019-02-12 04:00:00  min spent : 1085
```

Please help me solve this query . Thank you

Comment: _“But in my case 12 -2 -2019(4AM) to 13 -2 - 2019(3.59AM) is considered as one day”_ - well the database doesn’t know anything about that … you are simply grouping by the date part now, and that is just different for those two. So you would first of all need to find some way to group dates in that time range together. If this “offset” is constant across all records (and DST, if applicable), then you could maybe simply subtract 4 hours from these datetime values, and group on _that_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution :- 
Subtract  subtract 4 hours from datetime value and group

```
$sql = "SELECT driver_id , DATE(start_time - interval 4 hour),
SUM(minutes_spent) 
FROM driver_online_session 
where driver_id='3229' AND
start_time    BETWEEN '2019-02-11 03:59:59' AND  '2019-02-14 03:59:59'
GROUP by DATE(start_time - interval 4 hour)
ORDER BY date(start_time) DESC";
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the `start_time` from the group by (and from the select as well, probably) and just grouping by the driver ID instead (or not grouping by anything, since driver ID is already restricted to a single value)?

Since you're also restricting which start times can be returned to a single "day" (as defined by you), it should just return all rows where the start time is within the allowed range, and sum the total of all those rows. And since you already know the "day", you don't really need to output it.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  driver_id, sum(minutes_spent) 
FROM 
  driver_online_session 
WHERE
  driver_id='3229' AND
  start_time BETWEEN '2019-02-12 03:59:59' AND  '2019-02-13 03:59:59'
```

Of course if you need a more generic solution (e.g. where you can show many "days" at once) then this won't work too well - you'd have to find a way to group by your custom time range - but it gives you a starting point.

Comment: The above query fixed my issue.

Comment: But one issue ... here it should group by date ... the above query works for 2019-02-12 03:59:59' AND  '2019-02-13 03:59:59' 
but if its 2019-02-11 03:59:59' AND  '2019-02-13 03:59:59' 

It should  group the date by 2 rows 
2019-2-11  - Total min spent 
and 2019 -2 - 12 - Total min spent

Comment: Yes, that was essentially what I pointed out in my last paragraph. I haven't addressed that directly in the code sample because the question you asked was about the specific date range.

Comment: Is possible to display group by date  using query or should we add conditions ?

Comment: Possibly. As my answer notes, I haven't investigated it in detail. I answered the question about the precise situation which was described. If you want to take it further then you can either investigate it yourself, or ask a new question about this more complex scenario (or both!). In the meantime I feel my answer resolves your initial issue, so I humbly ask that you consider marking it as accepted.